# IIS Virtual Directory Map to different URL

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-8

So on a normal machine (i.e. not a server) running Win 8.1 I have this virtual directory on the `DefaultWebSite`, to get to it I type in Google `http://localhost/MyCoolSite`.

Now, I want to map that to `http://mycoolsite.com` or something similar - just not have it accessed via `http://localhost/MyCoolSite`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make [IIS rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) rule for mapping / to /MyCoolSite URLs. The second item you need to take care of resolving the mycoolsite.com hostname. For this you need to simply update the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host with your local IP with hostname. Like,

```
127.0.0.1       mycoolsite.com
```

Comment: So is the pattern `/` and the Action - Rewrite URL `/MyCoolSite`

Comment: Yes, this is the pattern.